# Regular expression to extract info from journal reference

Tags: regex, string, r, gsub

If I have a string with a given journal reference formatted as in

```
ref="Carlson, A., Bernier, U.R., Hogsette, J.A., and Sutton, B.D. 2001. Distinctive hydrocarbons of the black dump fly, Hydrotaea aenescens (Diptera: Muscidae). Arch. Insect Biochem. Physiol. 48:167-178."
```

then I would like to come up with good `gsub` expressions in R to extract the first author, journal and volume plus pages. For the year and author I already came up with

```
year=strsplit(sub('^\\D*', '',ref),". ")[[1]][[1]]
year
"2001"
author=gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]","",strsplit(ref,"\\., ")[[1]][[1]])
author
"Carlson A"
```

but I am having trouble finding a good expression for the journal and for the volume and pages. Anybody any thoughts perhaps? (The volume and pages should ideally be detected as the last characters of the string that either contain numbers, a full stop or a colon, and the journal should be comprised of the part that lies between the year and volume+pages after first removing the first part that lies between the year (plus full stop) and the next full stop, which should be the title)

cheers, Tom

Comment: Can you give an explicit output please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `gsub` here , just `strsplit`. This should be a good start:

```
ll <- unlist(strsplit(ref,','))
ll[1]
[1] "Carlson"

strsplit(tail(ll,1),'[.]')
[[1]]
[1] " Hydrotaea aenescens (Diptera: Muscidae)" " Arch"                                   
[3] " Insect Biochem"                          " Physiol"                                
[5] " 48:167-178"
```

Comment: Hey there - thanks - that's a good solution to get the volume & page numbers, but what about the journal title - that's more tricky to extract, no? ("Arch. Insect Biochem. Physiol.")

Comment: @TomWenseleers - I think you're stuffed on the journal title. I can't see how one could reliably determine where the paper title ends and the journal starts. Perhaps you could use common stems like `Arch.`, `Journal of` or `J.` or whatever to guess at it.

Comment: @TomWenseleers I don't know. I think SO contributors in the academic fields can be more helpful..

Comment: What about first removing the part of the string that lies between the year and the first full stop, and assuming that that is the title, and then to assume that the rest up to the volume information is the journal? But how would I do something like this most elegantly?